# Derivative of a piecewise function, at junction points.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In our midterm , we had a question that asks us to write the derivative of :
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2x-x^2, & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
x^2-2x, & 1 < x \leq 5
\end{cases} 
$$
and I chose that the derivative should be : $$f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2-2x, & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
2x-2, & 1 < x \leq 5
\end{cases} 
$$

but he ( my teacher ) says it should be : $$f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2-2x, & 0 < x < 1 \\
2x-2, & 1 < x < 5
\end{cases} 
$$

Difference between the 2 Answers is : changing $0 \leq $ to $0 < $ & changing $ \leq 5$ to $ < 5$ , that is , at the Over-all End Points , whether Derivative is Defined or not.

Now the argument I had in mind during the midterm was, say for example at $x = 0$:
$$ f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} $$
now this is basically the derivative at $x = 0$, except the limit here is two-sided, however; since f(x) is defined for $x \geq 0$ it shouldn't make sense to talk about the limit from the left, thus our limit is actually only a right sided limit.

$$ f'(0) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} $$
which evidently exists because $f(x)$ is continuous at $ x = 0 $ from the right.

Now, I didn't mention my argument to him as I'm not sure if it has any fallacies, but he countered my objection with the example of $ f(x) = \sqrt x $ and I'm honestly not sure if my argument is correct anymore, a flaw in my argument maybe that continuity doesn't imply differentiability.

Who/which is correct here? Also It'd be helpful if you provided an explanation as well.

Comment: This Post is well-written , but it has too many errors ! Was that the Exact Question & the Exact Answer & the Exact Example the Professor gave ? It is hard to respond based on what is given here !

Comment: @prem Everything here is exact...

Comment: @NormalHighstudent there are errors in your post...see clearly

Comment: The errors are Obvious , @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad , when those are rectified , we will know who is saying what , though currently we can not know who is Correct. What Professor is saying might turn out to be what OP is saying & vice-versa.

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Oh I'm sorry, i copied and pasted my mathjax and didnt realize that the derivative is wrong, I'm going to edit it out

Comment: Originally , the Post was such that Both were wrong. You have now made some Edits which move it more towards Correctness , but other Issues still remain [[ Such as : $f(1)$ has Duplicate Definition. Who is "he" ? Professor , I assume. What argument did Professor imply by $f(x)=\sqrt{2}$ ? It is not clear ]] OK , moving on to the Core Issue : you have Correctly left out the Derivative @ $x=1$ , which is the Exact Same Case at $x=0$ & at $x=5$ & hence Professor is Correct !!

Comment: @Prem I'm actually not sure what sign was it at x = 1, but I'm more focused on x = 0  and x = 5
What do you mean by I left them out?

Comment: When you look back at **" @prem Everything here is exact... – NormalHighstudent "** , & then consider all the changes which went in , you may wonder what was going on in my mind ! OK , I see that you have taken out $\le$ [ which gave Duplicate Definition for $f(1)$ ] & made it $<$ , which means $f(1)$ is "left out" & undefined. Likewise Derivative is undefined at $f(1)$ which is what I mean by "left out" & Professor also "left out" the Derivate at End Points , hence he is Correct !

Comment: @Prem yeah, I'm sorry for doubting you, today was a bit too much.
Can you elaborate why the derivative doesn't exist at the endpoints?

Comment: It is not a Question of "Doubting" me ( I am generally wrong ) , it is Question of accurate & clear Posting , which will enable accurate & clear Answers. I will Direct you to the Answer by @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad is elaborating about the End Points !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The latter is correct. A function isn't differentiable at the end points of an interval. This is so because, at the left end point the left hand derivative doesn't exist and at the right end point right hand derivative doesn't exist.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? (Whoever downvoted this)

Comment: [[ Not sure why & by whom , this was Downvoted ]] OP & Professor already used what you are Correctly claiming here , when Derivative was left undefined at $1$ because that is the End Point of the Intervals. That Same thought implies that the Derivative must be undefined at the other End Points of those Intervals too. Thus Derivative must not use $\le$ , it must use $<$ ......